# When trying to install Opencats using installwizard.php it gives some errors

Tags: php, linux, apache2, ubuntu-18.04, sudo

I tried to install opencats on linux server. Running ubuntu version is 18. When I try to install opencats via http://localhost/opencats (server ip address used as localhost) and click installwizard.php I get the following errors/warnings:

[image: screenshot opencats installwizard.php]

Answer (score 0):

It won't work on PHP7 if it wants the MySQL extension. It has been removed. Its sounds like a very very old project you are trying to install.

I had a quick look on their homepage:

> Opencats has a minimum supported PHP version of PHP 5.5, and are working towards full PHP 7 compatibility.

http://www.opencats.org/

Answer (score 0):

OpenCATS does not currently support php7. It must be 5.6.X

**you should install PHP5.6**, Open your terminal and execute those commands as follow:

1- to install PHP5.6

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6
```

2- Now, you should know which PHP version you are using

```
php --version
```

3- To stop running the current PHP version, run the commands below to disable it for Apache2 (ex: PHP7.2)

```
sudo a2dismod phpX
```

where **X** is your PHP version

4- Then run the commands below to enable PHP 5.6 for Apache2 to use

```
sudo a2enmod php5.6
```

5- Now, You can install the needed PHP extensions like MySQL

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mysql
```

5- Restart Apache2 for the changes to apply by running the commands below

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Hope that this can help you.